# How to save editable div content in array on button click

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am creating a web page, using html and php, where I want to display some questions and get the answers of the user. Currently, lets say I have the questions in an array like this

```
<?php 
$questions = array(
    '0' => array(
        'id'=>1,
        'q'=>'Test1'
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'id'=>2,
        'q'=>'Test2'
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'id'=>3,
        'q'=>'Test3'
    ),
    '3' => array(
        'id'=>4,
        'q'=>'Test4'
    ),
    '4' => array(
        'id'=>5,
        'q'=>'Test5'
    )
)
?>
```

I have the following div in my page,

```
<div class="question">
    <h5 id="quest">
        <?php echo $questions[0]['q']; ?>
    </h5>
</div>
```

and I use the following button and js function in order to display each question on button click.

```
<button onclick="javascript:SwapDivs()">
     Next
</button>

<script>
var count = 1;
function SwapDivs() {
    var questions = <?php echo json_encode($questions); ?>;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("h5#quest").html(questions[count]['q']);
        count++;
    });
}
</script>
```

Below my questions div I have an editable div like this

```
<div class="editable" contenteditable="true" data-text="Write your answer."></div>
```

and my question is how can I store users' answer for each question on next button click before showing him the next question, so as to store these answers to my database?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Tried to make json array of questions and their answers, after procesing send json array to server for saving data. (Inline edit style)

Comment: Hi Ranjeet Singh and thanks for the info. Could you give an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript can post to your php server directly without having to reload the page. It is done by using [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) (pure javascript) or jquery [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp).

Comment: Hmm, this could be a solution, but I have another button (Back button), so the user can return to previous question and change his answer.

Comment: No problem, then you just repost and update the database